# PHP - Retrieving Only Certain XML Nodes and Saving to a file

Tags: php, xml

I am using PHP curl to retrive an xml file from a remote url and save it to a local file on my server. The structure is the following:

```
<Store Country="Ireland">
<EventsPoints>
    <Event ID="1800" >
        <ArtistIDs>
            <ArtistID ID="109" Type="Primary" />
        </ArtistIDs>
        <CategoryID>1</CategoryID>
        <Country>IRL</Country>
        <PerformanceName>Music and Arts</PerformanceName>
        <VenueID ID="197" />
    </Event>
<Venues>
    <Venue ID="197">
        <City>Dublin</City>
        <Country>IRL</Country>
        <VenueName>ABC</VenueName>
        <VenueNumber>22</VenueNumber>
    </Venue>
</Venues>
```

The above xml blocks are stored in the same XML file. There are several Event blocks and several Venue blocks. 
The problem i'm having is using PHP to access this large XML file and iterate through the Venue blocks retrieving only a Venue block with a certain ID specified via a parameter. 
I then want to iterate through the event blocks - only retrieving the events matching this specified venue ID. I then want to save this to a file on the server. 
I want to do this for each venue.

How do I go about doing the above?

EDIT:

For each Venue and events related to that venue, I just want to literally copy them to their own file - basically splitting down the larger file into individual files

```
 $docSource = new DOMDocument();
$docSource->loadXML($xml);
$docDest = new DOMDocument();
$docDest->loadXML(file_get_contents('/var/www/html/xml/testfile.xml'));

$xpath = new DOMXPath($docSource);
$id = "197";
$result = $xpath->query('//Event/VenueID[@ID=$id]')->item(0); //Get directly the node you want

$result = $docDest->importNode($result, true); //Copy the node to the other document

$items = $docDest->getElementsByTagName('items')->item(0);
$items->appendChild($result); //Add the copied node to the destination document

echo $docDest->saveXML();
```

Comment: with XPath: `//Event/VenueID[@ID=$id]`

Comment: So would I just put this in a for each loop and then save to separate files?

Comment: Yes. Have a look at this [XPath tutorial](http://schlitt.info/opensource/blog/0704_xpath.html)

Comment: How do I keep it in the XML format though? For each Venue and events related to that venue, I just want to literally copy them to their own file - basically splitting down the larger file into individual files

Comment: Please update your question with the exact requirements. Maybe show the desired outfiles and explain where you are facing problems. Maybe show what you have tried so far.

Comment: can anyone please point out what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not showing the desired output format, so I will assume this generates what you want. If not, feel free to modify the code so it meets the desired output format. This along with the comments above should have all you need to get this working on your own.

```
// load Source document
$srcDom = new DOMDocument;
$srcDom->load('/var/www/html/xml/testfile.xml');
$xPath = new DOMXPath($srcDom);
// iterate over all the venues in the source document
foreach ($srcDom->getElementsByTagName('Venue') as $venue) {
    // create a new destination document for the current venue
    $dstDom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
    // add an EventsPoint element as the root node
    $dstDom->appendChild($dstDom->createElement('EventsPoint'));
    // import the Venue element tree to the new destination document
    $dstDom->documentElement->appendChild($dstDom->importNode($venue, true));
    // fetch all the events for the current venue from the source document
    $allEventsForVenue = $xPath->query(
        sprintf(
            '/Store/EventsPoints/Event[VenueID/@ID=%d]',
            $venue->getAttribute('ID')
        )
    );
    // iterate all the events found in Xpath query
    foreach ($allEventsForVenue as $event) {
        // add event element tree to current destination document
        $dstDom->documentElement->appendChild($dstDom->importNode($event, true));
    }
    // make output prettier
    $dstDom->formatOutput = true;
    // save XML to file named after venue ID
    $dstDom->save(sprintf('/path/to/%d.xml', $venue->getAttribute('ID')));
}
```

This will create an XML file like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EventsPoint>
  <Venue ID="197">
                <City>Dublin</City>
                <Country>IRL</Country>
                <VenueName>ABC</VenueName>
                <VenueNumber>22</VenueNumber>
            </Venue>
  <Event ID="1800">
            <ArtistIDs>
                <ArtistID ID="109" Type="Primary"/>
            </ArtistIDs>
            <CategoryID>1</CategoryID>
            <Country>IRL</Country>
            <PerformanceName>Music and Arts</PerformanceName>
            <VenueID ID="197"/>
        </Event>
</EventsPoint>
```

in the file 197.xml

Comment: Yea that's the output i'm looking for. I'm getting this error now: XML Parsing Error: junk after document element, <b>Catchable fatal error</b>:  Argument 1 passed to DOMXPath::__construct() must be an instance of DOMDocument,

Comment: @user1083813 make sure your source XML is valid to begin with

Comment: What about using the `not()` xpath function and removing all non-wanted?

Comment: the source XML is coming from a remote server which I can't edit so is there a way to disable the warning checks?

Comment: @user1083813 you can disable the parsing errors but that won't make the broken XML valid.

Comment: it doesn't seem to be saving it to the file